# Make two divs share the same scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

Given two divs that represent columns embedded in a larger div.  If the "!stuff" html represents many rows of data that would exceed the height of container, how do I set it up so the two col div's will overflow and share one scrollbar from "container"?

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;   
}

.col1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.col2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    !Stuff<br/>
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    !Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a fixed height for the container, otherwise it will be automatically resized so that the column divs fit inside. The `overflow` property should only be set for the container, as it is the only element that will be scrolled:

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;   
}

.col1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.col2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Html

```
<div class="col2"  onscroll="OnScroll(this)">!Stuff</div>
```

javascript function

```
function OnScroll(div) {
var div1 = document.getElementById("col1");
div1.scrollTop = div.scrollTop;}
```