# Make two divs share one scrollbar

Tags: css

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mycontent">
<div class="textarea" id="ingId" style="position:relative;">
        <div id="idComm" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; width: 450px; height: 151px; right: 18px; top: 1px;">
        </div>     
</div>    
</div>
```

How to make them share the same scrollbar? I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/hThsx/)

But it didn't work, since in the first div I have tinymce.

Comment: what do you mean to share same scrollbar

Comment: @Mr.Alien To have one scrollbar, and when the user will scroll, both divs to 'move'.

Comment: As I am thinking your code is fine, just reduce width to 90% so it will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hThsx/5/

Comment: Just as a hint : jqGrid does that when there's a horizontal scroll bar and a summary footer row.

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373786/make-two-divs-share-the-same-scrollbar